# Is there a simple way to change the required message TEXT, not placement, for radio buttons when using the jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button, message

I have several dozen groups of radio buttons, named to group them together. Contender_1 has 3-5 options, Contender_2 also has 3-5 options, and so on up to 40 or so groups of radio buttons. I have validation working using the jQuery Validate plugin, however I need to change the error message displayed for each group if at least one radio button per group isn't selected. Having looked on several other SO questions all the suggested responses advise naming each group and specifying a custom message for each, however that seems wasteful and unnecessarily repetitious since the message for all of them is the same ("Please vote for a contender in every category"). Is there a single statement that can achieve this?

Comment: No, I'm not asking about error message placement, but how to customise the error message _text_ for all radio button groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form_id').validate({
    rules:{
        radioname : 
        {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        radioname : 
        {
            required: "Your message"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way to use a wildcard for the name so that it can target all the similarly named radio button groups with one statement?